# Summing corresponding pairs from two lists within a tuple - in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, sum, tuples, transpose

I have a tuple containing two lists of numbers - ([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])

I need to sum together the corresponding pairs of numbers from each list. ie (1+5), (2+6) etc. Outputting a list ie [6,8,10,12]. It should also work for any amount of elements within the lists (2 lists of 5, 2 lists of 6 etc).

I've been trying a function using "map sum . transpose" but can't seem to get the types correct (as it is within a tuple). I found a piece of code on here which works for a list of lists, but don't know how to do the same for a tuple of lists (is it possible?). When I attempt to change the types of "a" or use Int I compile to type-mismatch errors.

```
tupSums :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
tupSums = map sum . transpose
```

I'm fairly new to using Haskell so I don't quite understand the errors I'm getting, sorry if the question seems stupid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good candidate for `zipWith`, which takes two lists and combines the corresponding elements in the list using a particular operator. The following should work:

```
tupSums :: Num a => ([a],[a]) -> [a]
tupSums = uncurry $ zipWith (+)
```

`zipWith (+)` evaluates to a function that takes two arguments, each of them being lists, and returns an list of pairwise sums. `uncurry` takes a function of two args and turns it into a function that takes a single tuple. So `uncurry $ zipWith (+)` evaluates to a function that takes a tuple of lists and returns a list with the pairwise sums.

Comment: Cheers Kevin, this is a great help. Mostly I'm having troubles with the differences between [a] and [Int] which is causing type mismatches when I curry functions.

Comment: @Worlt: `Int` is a concrete type that represents an integer. It also belongs to the `Num` typeclass, so anywhere that a `Num` is expected, you can use an `Int`. So in the type `Num a => ([a],[a]) -> [a]`, you can pass a `([Int],[Int])` in and you'll get an `[Int]` back out. The one restriction here is the concrete type of all 3 lists must be the same. You can't pass `([Int],[Integer])`, and if you pass `([Int],[Int])` in you can't get `[Integer]` back out.

Comment: @Worlt: Of course, you could write a more complicated function that has the type `Num a, b, c => ([a],[b]) -> [c]` if you want, but it's generally easier to do the transformations on your input/output instead of making the function itself try to be so extremely generic.

Comment: Ah right, that makes much more sense, I think I was getting confused as to what "a" actually was. Seems to be a placeholder type thing for any variable type you set it to. Also - my program is now fully functional, thank you so much!

Comment: @Worlt: Yep, if you see a lowercase character as a type, it's really just a placeholder. For example, with `id :: a -> a`, the type `a` is a placeholder for anything at all. But if the same placeholder is used twice it must be the same type both times, so you know that `id` must return the same type as it was given. And since it doesn't know anything about that type, you know that the only thing `id` can possibly return besides bottom is the argument it was given.

Comment: @Worlt: Of course, if you see `Num a => a -> a`, then you know that `a` can't be *anything*, it can only be an instance of the `Num` typeclass. But it could be any instance, so you don't know if it's `Int`, or `Integer`, or any of the other numeric types.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Ah, the main problem I was having was the type match for "a" and Int while trying to `mod` something, kept complaining about not having an Integral for [a], took a while to make it work but it seems to now!

Comment: @Worlt: `mod` works for anything in the `Integral` typeclass. If your function is declared as taking `[a]` then you can't `mod` the elements. If it's declared as taking `Integral a => [a]` then you can.

Comment: @KevinBallard: It's probably terribly bad practice but I seem to have gotten away with it by not specifying the types of my function and simply creating one as `map ('mod' 2)`.

Comment: @Worlt: Not specifying the types is perfectly reasonable in a lot of cases. Explicit type declarations are handy as documentation, and very handy for catching errors (e.g. if the function typechecks to the wrong type it will catch it there instead of where the function is called), and can be used to narrow the type of the function from one that might be overly-generic. But especially for simpler functions it's not necessary.